# Convert from Heic to Jpeg in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to use MagickImage in my ASP.NET Core project, targeting .NET 5, to convert Heic to Jpeg. I can install the library with no problem, however when I try to use it like below

```
using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(@"YourImage.jpg"))
{

}
```

I get an error

> Type or namespace could not be found

It recommends I change to `IMagickImage`. Also, the image I'm trying to convert is from `IFormFile`.

Does anyone know how I can convert this?

Answer (score 0):

I had to install the Cross-platform library